# Vue.js: How do I focus to an input just unhidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This must be something really basic, but I can't get it.

I have this piece of code in my `<template>`:

```
<div v-if="this.editable">
    <input type="text" ref="nota" :id="notaid" v-model="nombre" v-on:keyup.enter="enviar" v-on:blur="enviar" class="form-control">
</div>
<div v-else>
    <p @click="makeEditable">{{ nombre }}</p>
</div>
```

So, when the page loads, `editable=false` so it displays a text. When you click in the text there's a function that will make `editable` true, so it displays the input. This works fine. Now, my problem is, how do I focus on the `input` as soon as `editable` changes to true?

I have read some articles: [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/set-focus-on-input-vue/), [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-set-focus-to-input/10672), and some others that says I could be focusing on the element with some code as simple as:

```
this.$refs.nota.focus()
```

So `makeEditable` code is:

```
methods: {
  makeEditable() {
    this.editable = true;
    this.$refs.nota.focus()
  },
  ...
```

Problem is, I get this error:

```
app.js:38487 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"
```

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm trying to focus to an element that hasn't been created yet, because if I make the same on an `input` element that is always displayed, it works perfectly.

So which is the right way?

Comment: What if you try `Vue.nextTick(() => this.$refs.nota.focus())` after `this.editable = true;` ? It tells Vue to wait until the changes are made. See [the doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: You're genius man, that worked instantly. Thank you very much, would you like to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Vue.nextTick(callback)` as follow :

```js
methods: {
  makeEditable() {
    this.editable = true;
    Vue.nextTick(() => 
      this.$refs.nota.focus()
    )
  },
  ...
```

It tells Vue to wait until the changes are made and then call the callback.
See the [documentation for more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).